# [Plugin: WordPress.com Stats] Javascript not being added to footer

Tags: plugins

If you view the source code on my website, [loneplacebo.com](http://loneplacebo.com), you'll notice that only the comment

```
<!--stats_footer_test-->
```

is shown above the . The plugin doesn't seem to be adding the necessary javascript code to track my site's traffic. I tried deactivating and reactivating the plugin to no avail.

Comment: do you have `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` above the closing body tag in your footer.php

Comment: If this is added in the footer by the plugin, then the  wp_footer() should be there...

Comment: I use the Arras theme if that helps: http://www.arrastheme.com/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in place.

Comment: I checked my footer.php, and I found this above the </body> tag: `<?php 
arras_footer();
wp_footer(); 
?>`